# Проверка не пустоты свойства объекта

Tags: javascript

Например, есть объект:

```
var obj = {
   param: {
      param2: 12 
   }
}
```

Хочу добавить к `param2` единицу, то есть `obj.param.param2++`. Но так писать нельзя: может быть ошибка, поэтому мне нужно проверить:

```
if (obj && obj.param && obj.param.param2 && obj.param.param2 > 0)
```

**Вопрос.**
Как можно легко и элегантно проверять `obj.param.param2`, не проверяя всю цепочку?

Как пример, в языке PHP можно использовать функцию `is_empty($var['param'])`. Она вернет `true`, если есть какие-то проблемы с `$var['param']`, и не важно, существует она или просто пустая.

Comment: [В этом вопросе](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript) вот вагоны текста и кода по поводу того, как вообще правильно проверить наличие у объекта какого-то поля, а вы хотите несколько проверок изящно сделать... Могу лишь предложить использовать `try-catch` или идеи ООП: [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/63v57vyo/). Странный пример получился, но всё же.

Comment: пример, колосальный, о чем он вообще ;) Один обьект прячет значение в другом обьекте, а при чем тут упрощение проверок? Или имелось введу описывать структуры обьектов формально, и делать специальные функции для проверки переменных внутри этих структур?

Comment: Это же упрощенный пример, а не реальный случай. Суть в том, что во внешнем коде вас не интересует как там что устроено: просто используете `.setValue()` у `One`. В нём уже проверка задан ли `Second`, а в `Second` - что-то своё, если надо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо по очереди проходить по ветке свойств и создавать отсутствующие по пути свойства. Я бы сделал метод, которому передавать цепочку свойств как строку, и он бы создавал всё, что нужно, и инкрементировал св-во:

```
obj.plusplus('param.param2'); // obj.param.param2++
```

Метод примерно такой  ([фиддл](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/mhyht1r7/)):

```
var plusplus = function() {
    var args = arguments[0].split('.'), C = this, i;

    for( i = 0; i<args.length; i++) {
        if( !C.hasOwnProperty( args[i])) {
            C[ args[i]] = (i == args.length-1) ? 0 : {};
        }

        if( i == args.length-1) {
            C[ args[i]]++;
            return C[ args[i]];
        }
        C = C[ args[i]];
    }
}
```